# Band pass filter giving ‘wrong’ turning point

Tags: r, filter

I am trying to run a Christiano FitzGerald band pass filter to estimate a long-run trend (with period in excess of 70 years). My data are the demeaned natural log of a commodity price index. My problem is that the asymmetric CF filter output does not look right around the start and end points. In particular my long run trend has a peak a few years before the end point, which I think shouldn’t be there (by reference to previous work and also just from looking at the data, which seem to be still trending up).

[image: cf filter output, looks wrong][image: hp filter, looks good but not standard practice]

I have included R code below to replicate the issue in case that is useful. Any help would be very much appreciated! This is my first attempt at using this filter (this filter and the minimum period appear to be best practice for this kind of data).

```
library(mFilter)
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
d<-c(1.17, 1.11, 0.68, 0.83, 0.98, 1.01, 0.76, 0.52, 0.34, 0.36, 
0.18, 0.12, 0.07, -0.17, -0.47, -0.43, -0.01, -0.16, -0.51, -0.79, 
-0.69, -0.76, -0.86, -0.85, -0.78, -0.8, -0.89, -0.95, -0.83, 
-0.84, -0.96, -1.22, -1.41, -1.25, -0.94, -0.43, -0.58, -0.97, 
-0.82, -0.47, -0.44, -0.56, -0.55, -0.32, -0.31, -0.46, -0.34, 
-0.3, -0.25, -0.31, -0.57, -0.6, -0.42, -0.06, -0.3, -0.5, 0.12, 
0.3, 0.33, 0.24, 0.49, -0.18, -0.06, -0.15, -0.11, 0.02, 0.14, 
-0.3, -0.31, -0.28, -0.39, -0.94, -0.51, -0.74, -0.35, -0.37, 
-0.28, -0.22, -0.24, -0.36, -0.37, -0.32, -0.39, -0.45, -0.46, 
-0.48, -0.39, -0.21, 0.01, 0.02, 0.01, -0.06, -0.09, -0.04, -0.01, 
0, -0.02, 0.03, 0, -0.03, -0.05, -0.06, -0.07, -0.08, -0.11, 
-0.13, -0.15, -0.15, -0.18, -0.2, -0.24, -0.23, -0.25, -0.04, 
0.86, 0.8, 0.8, 0.81, 0.73, 1.03, 1.36, 1.33, 1.18, 1.06, 0.98, 
0.9, 0.22, 0.46, 0.25, 0.4, 0.59, 0.39, 0.33, 0.19, 0.11, 0.14, 
0.27, 0.19, -0.16, 0.11, 0.5, 0.32, 0.31, 0.46, 0.72, 1, 1.12, 
1.19, 1.47, 0.99, 1.23, 1.38, 1.35)
d<-data.frame(orig.series=d)
d$year<-as.numeric(row.names(d))
filter.output<-cffilter(d$orig.series,pl=70,pu=1500)
d$long.run.trend<-filter.output$cycle
d<-melt(d,id='year')
gp<-ggplot(d) + geom_line(aes(x=year,y=value,colour=variable))
gp
```

Comment: I think it would be easier to help you if you clarify your question a bit more.

Comment: thanks @fredrikhs. i'm basically wondering if anyone is aware of anything I may be doing wrong in specifying the filter. as I said I have never used it before. For example it is possible to specify a unit root and drift, but I don't think I want to use either of these because the filter as specified is free to have a very long period which I would think would capture a drifting or non-stationary process over the window given (around 150 data points). So I'm left wondering is there a step I am leaving out or something else I'm not aware of.

Comment: I ran a Hodrick Prescott Filter on the same data with lambda = 7000 and the output here looks closer to what I expected, it doesn't give a turning point near the end. However best practice appears to be to use the CF filter. So I guess I'm trying to force my CF filter to be more like the HP filter, but obviously I would like to get some understanding of what I am doing wrong if possible. Not sure if that helps...